# Android Runtime Permissions Causing too Many ANRs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, runtime-permissions

To make my app work on all Android Versions I had to ask for permissions at runtime from Android M and Onwards. I am developing in Unity 5.6.2
Before the current version of my app there were no ANRs reported on Google Play Console but after I have pushed the latest Update the number of ANRs have risen.
I only created a custom Activity Class and put code for permissions in it. I am not able to understand what could be the issue and why so many ANRs are occurring.

Please see the code below for asking runtime permissions and tell me what solution I should implement for my problem. Can you see anything in fthe code which could be causing this issue?

```
public class CustomUnityPlayerActivityForPermissions extends UnityPlayerActivity {

private String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
private ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        AskForPermissions();
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TestApp","No Need to Ask for Permissions API Levels < 23");

    }
}

public void AskForPermissions(){

    Log.d("TestApp","in AskPermission");
    for(int i = 0 ; i< permissions.length ; i++)

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UnityPlayer.currentActivity,
            permissions[i]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            permissionsToRequest.add(permissions[i]);

        }
    if(permissionsToRequest.size()>0) {

        Log.d("TestApp", "in AskPermission " + permissionsToRequest.size());
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), 1);
        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                finish();
            }
            return;


        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.

}

}
```

Comment: In my personal experience, the code to check runtime persmissions has never caused ANRs. I think your problem is somewhere else...

Comment: but I havent done any thing else other than asking for runtime permissions.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong above. Do your ANR reports in the Play Console give any details about what is happening when the ANR occurs? If so could you share it in the question?

Comment: I can share but that will not help, those are in alien language :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the ANR is caused by the section:

```
// permission was granted, yay! Do the
// contacts-related task you need to do.
```

If these tasks are slow, but you are doing them all the callback thread from the framework (which is where `onRequestPermissionsResult()` might be called from, it could potentially cause your app to be unresponsive. If you change the tasks which require permissions to be Asynchronous tasks, or find some other way of not doing them on the callback, do you stop the ANRs happening?

Comment: so you are suggesting that I should ask for permissions as Async Tasks?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that having got the result of the permissions request, you should do whatever it is you want to do next in an async task